# Need to get most recent chapter within book

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with the following columns in a MySQL database.

```
Chapters
   Columns:
     id int(11) AI PK 
     title varchar(100) 
     text varchar(10000) 
     created datetime 
     revision int(11) 
     book_id int(11)
```

Each book (book_id) can have multiple chapters.  Each chapter can have multiple revisions.  I'm trying to get a query that returns the most recent revision of each chapter for each book.  I've done this but it isn't doing what I want.

```
select max(id), title, text, min(created), max(revision) 
from chapters
group by book_id, title;
```

That gets me the max revision number, proper id of the revision and when the chapter was originally created.  However the text for the chapter isn't the text of the latest revision.  I can see why that is but I don't know how to fix it to get what I want.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Based on the answers below I got the idea for the following query.

```
select id, title, text, revision, created, book_id
from chapters
where id in (select max(id)
             from chapters
             group by book_id, title)
```

Now this gets the information I want except for 1 thing.  The created field in this query is the date that the latest revision for that chapter was created.  That's not a bad piece of information to have and I don't mind keeping it.  However, I also need the created date for the earliest revision for each chapter.

Let's say I have the following data.

```
id,  title,  text,  revision, created,    book_id
-------------------------------------------------
1 | Chpt 1 | Blah  | 1      | 23/2/2014 | 1
-------------------------------------------------
2 | Chpt 2 | Blah2 | 1      | 24/2/2014 | 1
-------------------------------------------------
3 | Chpt 1 | Blah3 | 2      | 25/2/2014 | 1
-------------------------------------------------
4 | Chpt 1 | Blah4 | 1      | 26/2/2014 | 2
-------------------------------------------------
5 | Chpt 3 | Blah5 | 1      | 27/2/2014 | 1
-------------------------------------------------
6 | Chpt 1 | Blah6 | 3      | 28/2/2014 | 1
```

After running the query I'd like the follow data.

```
id,  title,  text,  revision, created,    rev_date,  book_id
------------------------------------------------------------
6 | Chpt 1 | Blah6 | 3      | 23/2/2014 | 28/2/2014 | 1
------------------------------------------------------------
2 | Chpt 2 | Blah2 | 1      | 24/2/2014 | 24/2/2014 | 1
------------------------------------------------------------
5 | Chpt 3 | Blah5 | 1      | 27/2/2014 | 27/2/2014 | 1
------------------------------------------------------------
4 | Chpt 1 | Blah4 | 1      | 26/2/2014 | 26/2/2014 | 2
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Andrew

**Adding some clarification.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered.  All 3 answers helped on the way to the final solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's mysql, you can do it thus;

```
select * from (
    select * from chapters
    order by revision desc) x
group by book_id, title
```

This non-standard grouping functionality is a mysql-only trick, and although the documentation says the actual row you get for each group is non deterministic in reality it is completely deterministic: It's always the *first* row encountered. If you sort first, then group (as I have) you'll get the most recently revision of each chapter for each book.

Comment: This is very, very close to what I'm looking for.  Is there any way to get the lowest "created" date as well.  I've revised my question up above to show what I mean.

Comment: I got it.  Just took a small modification of your code.

`select id, title, text, created as rev_date, min(created) as created, revision, book_id from (
    select  id, title, text, created, revision, book_id from chapters
    order by revision desc) x
group by book_id, title
order by created`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. Effectively we are grabbing the top 1 result from the data ordered by the criteria you mentioned.

```
select id, title, text, created, revision 
from chapters
order by id desc, created asc, revision desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT chapters.id, title, text, min_create, max_revision
FROM chapters INNER JOIN
(
    select book_id, max(id) AS max_id,
           MIN(created) AS min_create, MAX(revision) AS max_revision
    from chapters
    group by book_id
) max_tab ON chapters.id = max_tab.max_id;
```